# implementing i18n spring mvc with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have to develop spring MVC web application with hibernate ORM. My application should be multilingual. what I understood is to develop i18n for my app. My question is that is there any good tutorial for i18n hibernate with spring? please help

Answer (score 1):

i18n and data persistence (ie hibernate ORM) is a different concept. Since you mentioned Spring, I would suggest start with [Spring's i18n support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource).

A good way to start is to create a [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) project on [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts).

1. File -> New -> Spring Roo Project -> (enter project name, top level pkg) -> select packaging WAR
2. On the Roo Shell, setup mvc by using `web mvc setup`
3. Run the resulting project using maven embedded tomcat container `mvn clean tomcat:run`

You will get a Spring MVC project complete with i18n and language switcher.

Just a little taste on how you can localize your app:

```
# File: messages.properties -----------
...
hello_prefix=Hello {0}
...

# File: messages_zh_CN.properties -----
...
hello_prefix=你好 {0}
...
```

Switch locale to Chinese simplified using `http://mycoolwebsite.com?lang=zh_CN

And on your JSP view obtain the locale specific message using

```
<spring:message code="hello_prefix" arguments="${name}"/>
```

Which will result into "Hello ${name}" for default locale and 你好 ${name} on chinese simplified locale